# Why and when would a ResponseWriter generate raw html?

Tags: html, templates, go

I don't understand why the code is generating the view.html and post.html data correctly but displaying it all as raw text. I had been following the guide [here](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) and as I was building it, I thought that the generated html from the Execute function would be sent to the ResponserWriter which would handle displaying it, but the error I'm getting seems to indicate my understanding of Execute or the ResponseWriter is wrong.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "bufio"
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
)

type UserPost struct {
    Name string
    About string
    PostTime string
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Recieved...")
        panic(e)
    }
}


func lineCounter(workingFile *os.File) int {
    fileScanner := bufio.NewScanner(workingFile)
    lineCount := 0
    for fileScanner.Scan() {
        lineCount++
    }
    return lineCount
}

func loadPage(i int) (*UserPost, error) {
    Posts,err := os.Open("dataf.txt")
    check(err)
    var PostArray [512]UserPost = parsePosts(Posts,i)
    Name := PostArray[i].Name 
    About := PostArray[i].About
    PostTime := PostArray[i].PostTime
    Posts.Close()
    return &UserPost{Name: Name[:len(Name)-1], About: About[:len(About)-1], PostTime: PostTime[:len(PostTime)-1]}, nil
}

func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmp,err := os.Open("dataf.txt")
    check(err)
    num := (lineCounter(tmp)/3)
    tmp.Close()
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        p, _ := loadPage(i)
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("view.html")
        t.Execute(w, p)
    }
    p := UserPost{Name: "", About: "", PostTime: ""}
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("post.html")
    t.Execute(w, p)
}

func inputHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    Name := r.FormValue("person")
    About := r.FormValue("body")
    PostTime := time.Now().String()

    filePaste,err := os.OpenFile("dataf.txt", os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREATE | os.O_APPEND | os.SEEK_END, 0666)
    check(err)
    filePaste.WriteString(Name+"~\n")
    filePaste.WriteString(About+"~\n")
    filePaste.WriteString(PostTime+"~\n")
    filePaste.Close()
    fmt.Println("Data recieved: ", Name,About,PostTime)
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/#bottom", http.StatusFound) //Use "/#bottom" to go to bottom of html page.
}

//os.File is the file type.
func parsePosts(fileToParse *os.File,num int) [512]UserPost {
    var buffer [512]UserPost
    reader := bufio.NewReader(fileToParse)  

    //This For loop reads each "forum post" then saves it to the buffer, then iterates to the next.
    for i := 0;i <= num; i++ {
        currentPost := new(UserPost)
        str, err := reader.ReadString('~')
        check(err)
        currentPost.Name = str

        //I search for '~' because my files save the end of reading line with that, so i can keep formatting saved (\n placement).
        str2, err2 := reader.ReadString('~')
        check(err2)
        currentPost.About = str2

        str3, err3 := reader.ReadString('~')
        check(err3)
        currentPost.PostTime = str3

        buffer[i] = *currentPost
        }   
    return buffer
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Listening...")
    http.HandleFunc("/", viewHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/post/", inputHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

view.html

```
<h4>{{.Name}}</h4>

<font size="3">
    <div>{{printf "%s" .About}}</div>
</font>
<br>
<font size="2" align="right">
    <div align="right">{{.PostTime}}</div>
</font>
```

post.html

```
<form action="/post/" method="POST">

<div><textarea name="person" rows="1" cols="30">{{printf "%s" .Name}}</textarea></div>

<div><textarea name="body" rows="5" cols="100">{{printf "%s" .About}}</textarea></div>

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>

<a name="bottom"></a>
</form>
```

I've currently been reading from an empty dataf.txt file.

Comment: You're not specifying the content type in the HTTP response headers. Try adding a Content-Type header.

Comment: @joshlf I went ahead and added the following line of code to both of my response headers.
`w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Orgin", "*")`

Unfortunately no changes.

Comment: Just like @joshlf stated, you need to set the content type and not the origin access control.  So for if you want your output to be html, you would do:
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")

Comment: Well, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is not "Content-Type", so your "no changes" is to be expected. joshlf asked for Content-Type and he is right.

Comment: @SamPhomsopha I went ahead and implemented the w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html") and it's working perfectly now.

Earlier I had read that if you didn't specify the content type, it was handled for you. And in the case of the guide I had been reading, there was never the necessity to set it, why's that?

Comment: The function that does the detection is DetectContentType (implementation [here](https://golang.org/src/net/http/sniff.go?s=648:690#L11)). It's a pretty simple function - basically it just tries to match against a list of very simple text-based signatures, and see if any matches. The HTML signatures (see [here](https://golang.org/src/net/http/sniff.go#L54)) don't include `<form>` or `<h4>`, and since those are the tags your resources start with, that's what it'd need to match in order to properly detect the content type (since it just pays attention to the first few bytes).

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that if you sent a document starting with `<html>`, the detection would be successful.

Comment: @joshlf Ah, okay now this is making a lot more sense. When I was working with a smaller post.html file it had been working but all of a sudden after a few edits it quit displaying properly. At the time I had also done a few edits with the code and thought I had done something to disturb something leading to the ResponseWriter.

Just for my own understanding, since I had altered the start of my view.html file, the detection array no longer contained a signature that matched with an item in the HTML signature array. So the content type wasn't set properly and resulted in displaying the raw text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted, it's because you haven't set the content type. Quoting from [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter):

```
// Write writes the data to the connection as part of an HTTP reply.
// If WriteHeader has not yet been called, Write calls WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
// before writing the data.  If the Header does not contain a
// Content-Type line, Write adds a Content-Type set to the result of passing
// the initial 512 bytes of written data to DetectContentType.
Write([]byte) (int, error)
```

If you don't set the content type yourself, first call to `ResponseWriter.Write()` will call [`http.DetectContentType()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#DetectContentType) to guess what to set. If the content you send starts with `"<form>"`, it won't be detected as HTML, but `"text/plain; charset=utf-8"` will be set (which "instructs" the browser to display the content as text and not try to interpret it as HTML).

If the content would start with `"<html>"` for example, content type `"text/html; charset=utf-8"` would be set automatically and it would work without further actions.

But don't rely on automatic detection if you know what you're sending, also it's much faster to set it yourself than to run a detection algorithm on it, so simply add this line before writing/sending any data:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
```

And also make your `post.html` template a complete, valid HTML document.

Also another piece of advice: in your code you religiously omit checking returned errors. Don't do that. The least you could do is print them on the console. You will save a lot of time for yourself if you don't omit errors.

Comment: I had totally overlooked the cost of the detection algorithm in my earlier conclusion I had come to when replying to joshlf. How and why I got my error is much clearer now.

Thanks everyone!